# Different paper orientation in a document lyx

Tags: margins, lyx, geometry, landscape

I have to change the orientation from portrait to landscape in the middle of a document. Only for 1 until 3 pages after that it have to portrait again.

I use this code in texmaker and running well

```
\newgeometry{landscape}
```

and use `restoregeometry` to get portrait again

But when I try to insert the code in LyX, I don't get an error message but the result is still in portrait. could anyone tell me why? And how to produce landscape pages in the middle a document in LyX?

Comment: I set degree to rotate the picture in lyx graphics.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with LyX, but instead of `\newgeometry{landscape}` you could try using the [lscape](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lscape) package from the [graphics](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics) package bundle (`\begin{landscape}`...`\end{landscape}`) or [pdflscape](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) package (if you want to produce a pdf, same `\begin...\end`) or another package found at http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=lscape&search_type=description.

Comment: I solved my problem by trick : set degree to rotate the picture in lyx graphics, but it seems can't be used to rotate the caption. btw thanks for the references.

Comment: @Verly: Don't hesitate to post your solution as an answer of its own and to accept it afterwards, if that's how you solved your problem.